# How to Read from a Text File, Character by Character in C++

Tags: c++, file, text, character

I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to read from a text file in C++, character by character. That way, I could have a while loop (while there's still text left) where I store the next character in the text document in a temp variable so I could do something with it, then repeat the process with the next character. I know how to open the file and everything, but `temp = textFile.getchar()` doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 58):

You could try something like:

```
char ch;
fstream fin("file", fstream::in);
while (fin >> noskipws >> ch) {
    cout << ch; // Or whatever
}
```

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah, I like it because that's what `C` does when reading single characters.

Comment: The argument you put there `noskipws` is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 14):

@cnicutar and @Pete Becker have already pointed out the possibility of using `noskipws`/unsetting `skipws` to read a character at a time without skipping over white space characters in the input.

Another possibility would be to use an `istreambuf_iterator` to read the data. Along with this, I'd generally use a standard algorithm like `std::transform` to do the reading and processing.

Just for example, let's assume we wanted to do a Caesar-like cipher, copying from standard input to standard output, but adding 3 to every upper-case character, so `A` would become `D`, `B` could become `E`, etc. (and at the end, it would wrap around so `XYZ` converted to `ABC`.

If we were going to do that in C, we'd typically use a loop something like this:

```
int ch;
while (EOF != (ch = getchar())) {
    if (isupper(ch)) 
        ch = ((ch - 'A') +3) % 26 + 'A';
    putchar(ch);
}
```

To do the same thing in C++, I'd probably write the code more like this:

```
std::transform(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin),
               std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(),
               std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cout),
               [](int ch) { return isupper(ch) ? ((ch - 'A') + 3) % 26 + 'A' : ch;});
```

Doing the job this way, you receive the consecutive characters as the values of the parameter passed to (in this case) the lambda function (though you could use an explicit functor instead of a lambda if you preferred).

Answer (score 13):

To quote Bjarne Stroustrup:"The >> operator is intended for formatted input; that is, reading objects of an expected type and format. Where this is not desirable and we want to read charactes as characters and then examine them, we use the get() functions."

```
char c;
while (input.get(c))
{
    // do something with c
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a c++ stylish function your can use to read files char by char.

```
void readCharFile(string &filePath) {
    ifstream in(filePath);
    char c;

    if(in.is_open()) {
        while(in.good()) {
            in.get(c);
            // Play with the data
        }
    }

    if(!in.eof() && in.fail())
        cout << "error reading " << filePath << endl;

    in.close();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    //Variables
    char END_OF_FILE = '#';
    char singleCharacter;

    //Get a character from the input file
    inFile.get(singleCharacter);

    //Read the file until it reaches #
    //When read pointer reads the # it will exit loop
    //This requires that you have a # sign as last character in your text file

    while (singleCharacter != END_OF_FILE)
    {
         cout << singleCharacter;
         inFile.get(singleCharacter);
    }

   //If you need to store each character, declare a variable and store it
   //in the while loop.
```

Answer (score 2):

Re: `textFile.getch()`, did you make that up, or do you have a reference that says it should work? If it's the latter, get rid of it. If it's the former, don't do that. Get a good reference.

```
char ch;
textFile.unsetf(ios_base::skipws);
textFile >> ch;
```

Comment: Yup. That's why @cnicular used `noskipws`. I've just edited mine to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `temp` is a `char`  and `textFile` is a `std::fstream` derivative...

The syntax you're looking for is

```
textFile.get( temp );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason not to use C `<stdio.h>` in C++, and in fact it is often the optimal choice.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()  // (void) not necessary in C++
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        // do something with 'c' here
    }
    return 0; // technically not necessary in C++ but still good style
}
```

Comment: Old thread, etc. But question is "from file." You can't use `getchar` to read from anything other than stdin. `getc` is what you want; and you'll have to open a file pointer somewhere.