# C++ ifstream not reading \n?

Tags: c++, text, project, newline, ifstream

I'm trying to do operations per-line of a text file, and the way I have it right now, my `ifstream` object isn't detecting the `\n` character for each line, which is required for this project. Here's how I have it right now:

```cpp
std::ifstream instream;
instream >> value;
while (value != '\n')
{
    // do code and such
}
```

But when I have it run the loop, all I'm getting is a single line of everything in the program. While it is doing exactly what it is supposed to in the loop, I NEED the `\n` to be recognized. Here's my `.txt` file:

```
LXXXVII
cCxiX
MCCCLIV
CXXXLL
MMDCLXXIII
DXLCC
MCdLxxvI
XZ
X
IV
```

Exactly like that. I cannot change it.

Comment: what data type is `value`?  You might want to use `value = cin.get()` instead of `cin >> value`.

Comment: If you want to read lines, use a function that reads lines. By "\n", what you really mean is an *empty* line.

Comment: value is a char type, and it cannot be an array of any kind, so what would i use instead? and @DavidSchwartz, by \n i really mean the end of the line.

Comment: Read about `getline`.

Comment: @wbAnon Based on your comment, Ben Voigt's comment should solve your problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `>>` operator does a "formatted input operation" which means (among other things) it skips whitespace.

To read raw characters one by one without skipping whitespace you need to use an "unformatted input operation" such as `istream::get()`.  Assuming `value` is of type `char`, you can read each char with `instream.get(value)`

When you reach EOF the read will fail, so you can read every character in a loop such as:

```
while (instream.get(value))
  // process value
```

However, to read line-by-line you could read into a `std::string` and use `std::getline`

```
std::string line;
while (getline(instream, line))
  // ...
```

This is an unformatted input operation which reads everything up to a `\n` into the string, then discards the `\n` character (so you'd need to manually append a `\n` after each erad line to reconstruct the original input)

Comment: alright, i see where you're coming from. so will i get a \n as the value of `value`?

Comment: When using `instream.get(value)` yes, assuming `value` is of type `char`

Comment: ok, well the code `instream.get(value)` is not giving value assigning the `\n`. any idea as to why?

Comment: Why don't you just read the whole line into a std::string with getline? You can parse the string at will afterwards and don't need to fuzz around with \n, as it's stripped from the std::string, as Jonathan explained.

Comment: because i cant use a string for the assignment. at all

Comment: For what assignment specifically?

Comment: This code works great and should produce what you'd like to have: http://ideone.com/UX6RJw (C++11 due to the auto keyword.)     Output: http://pastie.org/private/umsqfcnyh3fpgjx3obyzw

Comment: again, i cannot use a string. only char

Comment: @wbAnon, this works fine for me (using `string` for convenience): http://ideone.com/HkEZka If similar code doesn't work for you then either you're doing something wrong or your file has no `\n` characters. If you created the file on Windows watch out for \r characters in the file too, due to Windows' stupid line endings

Comment: ya i know... i just got it to work too. not sure why or what i did tho XD

Answer (score 3):

You can read your file as follows:

```cpp
ifstream instream("file.txt");
string line;
while (instream >> line)
{
    cout << line;
    if (instream.peek() == '\n') // detect '\n'
    {
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

This way you can track where the line in file ends and detect end of file.

Comment: @wbAnon If this is the case, please see " http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240010/how-to-read-from-a-text-file-character-by-character-in-c" for some information

Comment: i know how to get it to read the file char by char, the problem is that it refuses to read the \n character at the end of each line.

Comment: @wbAnon  try to use fstream::get() instead?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for this:
`instream.unsetf(std::ios_base::skipws)`