# Checking a character to be a newline

Tags: c, char

How to check whether a character is a newline character in any encoding in C?

I have a task to write my own ***wc*** program. And if I use just if `(s[i] == '\n')` it has another answer than original ***wc*** if I call it to itself.
Here is the code:

```
typedef struct
{
    int newline;
    int word;
    int byte;
} info;

info count(int descr)
{
    info kol;
    kol.newline = 0;
    kol.word = 0;
    kol.byte = 0;

    int len = 512;
    char s[512];
    int n;

    errno = 0;
    int flag1 = 1;
    int flag2 = 1;
    while(n = read(descr, s, len))
    {
        if(n == -1)
            error("Error while reading.", errno);

        errno = 0; 

        kol.byte+=n;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            if(flag1)
            {
                kol.newline++;
                flag1 = 0;
            }

            if(isblank(s[i]) || s[i] == '\n')
                flag2 = 1;
            else
            {
                if(flag2)
                {
                    kol.word++;
                    flag2 = 0;
                }
            }
            if(s[i] == '\n')
                flag1 = 1;
        }
    }
    return kol;
}
```

It works fine for all text files, but when I call it to file I got after compiling itself it  does't give the answer ***wc*** gives.

Comment: You mean like `'\n'`?

Comment: '\n' is working only in ASCII encoding.  
I mean something like _isdigit()_ function

Comment: You call `read(descr)`, where `descr` is presumably a file descriptor. How was it opened? And *how* does your output differ from that of `wc`, and on what input?

Comment: `descr` is opened in other part of program `int descr = open(argv[i], 0);`.  Difference:
`wc:   5   27 2520 count.o`  
`my_wc:    6   17 2520 count.o`.
On input I give [this](http://pastebin.com/f4nY5Kbj) compiled with `gcc -std=c99 -c -o count.o count.c`

Comment: it looks like you're calling wc on a binary file... as it is not made for this, I'm not sure it will output any meaningful result. Maybe the problem is related to "unterminated" lines (e.g. if the last one does not finish with a newline).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way to check whether a character `s[i]` is a newline character is simply:

```
if (s[i] == '\n')
```

If you're reading from a file that's been opened in text mode (including `stdin`), then whatever representation the underlying system uses to mark the end of a line will be translated to a single `'\n'` character.

You say you're trying to write your own `wc` program, and by comparing to `'\n'` you're getting different results than the system's `wc`. You haven't told us enough to guess why that's happening. Show us your code and tell us exactly what's happening.

You might run into problems if you're reading a file that's encoded differently -- say, trying to read a Unix-format text file on a Windows system. But then `wc` would have the same problem.

Comment: C newbie is here < it took 10 minutes till I realized that `'\n'` is not `"\n"` :D

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240035/11322237) may help someone later. It's about not skipping white spaces when reading from a file.

Comment: @JusticeBringer Perhaps, but the link is specific to C++, not C.

Comment: Indeed, you're right, didn't pay attention to that.Still you don't know who is going to need this later.

Answer (score 6):

There are several newline characters in ASCII and Unicode.

The most famous are `\r` and `\n`, from ASCII. Technically these are carriage return and line-feed. Windows uses both together `\r\n` (technically carriage-return means go to column 0, line-feed means go to next line, but nothing I know of obeys that in practice), unix uses just `\n`. Some (not common) OSs use just `\r`.

Most apps stop there, and don't suffer for it. What follows is more theoretical.

Unicode complicates things. U+000A and U+000B are identical to `\r` and `\n` (same binary representation in UTF-8). Then there's U+0085 "next line", U+2028 "line separator" and U+2029 "paragraph separator". You can also check vertical tab (U+000B) if you want to check everything. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Unicode

Comment: @xtofpernaud well I know there was a trick with very old printers to make them overprint characters to draw pictures, but I was really referring to anything which is still generally used!

Comment: \r\n is still used, for example all line-based protocols (e.g., SMTP, IMAP, POP3) and other ones (e.g., HTTP headers) use \r\n as line ending. And also if you send data to a terminal at low level, I'm quite sure that the \r is still required to return at column 0.

Comment: If you're reading in text mode, you don't have to worry about anything other than `'\n'`. Whatever representation the OS uses will be translated.

Comment: @Ale: The terminal is an interesting one; rings a bell for making progress bars. HTTP doesn't have any way of handling a `\r` or `\n` on its own so that just means it behaves like windows, rather than obeying the literal meaning of the characters.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Text mode doesn't necessarily normalise everything. Also it can cause EOF characters to cause the literal end-of-file, so isn't always the best thing to use (personally I prefer handling line endings myself)

Comment: A big problem with text mode is if the text file isn't in the native text format, you'll get all sorts of problems.

Comment: @Dave Indeed several programs (e.g., wget, curl, scp) use '\r' to return to the beginning of the line and display progress bars or update status info.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no standard function like the `isXXXXX()` ones (the closest one is `isspace()`, which is true also for other conditions (space, tab, form feed...). Simply comparing to `'\n'` should solve your problem; depending on what you consider to be a newline character, you might also want to check for `'\r'` (carriage return). UNIX standard as line separator is `'\n'`, Mac (before OS X) used `'\r'` (now `'\n'` is more common, but `'\r'` is sometimes still used by some applications, e.g. MS Office), DOS/Windows use the `"\r\n"` sequence.

Comment: Mac OS X uses `\n` and not `\r`.

Comment: Not in all applications (see for example CSV files exported by Excel on OS X)

Comment: @Ale that's probably more because Microsoft didn't notice it had changed in the update… in general it's `\n` now, but it doesn't matter because you should always check for *anything*. You never know when a user has copied a file from another OS.

Comment: Right, MS didn't realize that now OS X is UNIX-based maybe ;-) I clarified my reply.

Comment: If you're reading in text mode, you don't have to worry about anything other than `'\n'`. Whatever representation the OS uses will be translated.