# How to read the entire content of a file character by character?

Tags: c++, file

There is a file containing data like the following:

```
11619.
Jody rosy.
32.
north st.
1/8/2013.
52.
```

I would like to read the entire file content as follows:

```
1
1
6
1
9
.

J
o
d
y

etc.
```

How can I read the file content that way?

Comment: How far did you get before having to ask desperately for help?

Comment: `std::ifstream fs("file.ext"); int ch = fs.get();`

Comment: Have you taken the time to look at the documentation for [`std::istream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream)?

Comment: @Jongware: sorry I don't understand, but what do you mean?

Comment: @LionKing - he means "show some code". What did you try?

Comment: google : "C++ read file" would give you the solution quickly

Comment: @Jongware: because I don't know the way to try.

Comment: @LionKing Then you google it...

Comment: What is the problem if I didn't know, I ask someone else who knows

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Read from a Text File, Character by Character in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240010/how-to-read-from-a-text-file-character-by-character-in-c)

Comment: @LionKing The problem is not that you asked - it's rather that you asked before trying anything. As Akinaru has already pointed it out: "google : "C++ read file" would give you the solution quickly"...

Comment: @lion-king: Looking back in your Questions history, I notice you have been *trained* not to show your own attempts. That is, whether or not you supplied your own code, you would get a properly formed, working routine *anyway*. While a good short term solution -- copy and paste -- it also shows your are not learning to write code, you are only learning how to copy and paste.

Comment: @H2CO3: I'm already tried, and  I did not find what I want, I have seen some examples, but I've found as difficult for a beginner.

Comment: @LionKing I see. That's good news. In this case, next time please **make sure to include the code you have already tried.** If you don't, you will naturally be assumed to have tried nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this like this:

```
std::ifstream infile("myfile.txt");
char ch;
while(infile.get(ch))
{
   ... process ch ... 
}
```

This avoids the problems that appear on the last character, or having to read a character before the first iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use `std::ifstream`:

```
std::ifstream fs("file.ext");
int ch = fs.get();

while (fs.good()) {
    // process `ch' then
    ch = fs.get();
}
```

Comment: This isn't really idiomatic (also, did you mean `char`?). Why not `while(fs >> ch) { /* do stuff with ch */ }`?

Comment: @Rapptz No, I meant `int`. Why not? Because this doesn't rely on the type of `ch`.

Comment: That makes almost no sense to me.

Comment: @Rapptz Specifically what? Also, feel free to write an answer if you don't find any of the current ones satisfactory.

Comment: How does it "not rely on the type of `ch`"? The `while(fs >> ch)` syntax works on any type where `operator>>` is overloaded.

Comment: @Rapptz If you are reading into an `int` (as I do - what if one day you want to get the `EOF` character out for some reason?), then `operator>>(int)` will read the first `11619` sequence of characters as one integer... not something we want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34769/discussion-between-h2co3-and-rapptz)

Answer (score 2):

Iterators were made for this- specifically, `std::istream_iterator<char>.` It's far more useful than using `get()` or `read()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  char c;
  file >> c;
```

Or

```
  char c;
  file.read((unsigned char *) &c, sizeof(c));
```

Comment: Typo, sorry missed the ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream input("file.txt");
    while (input)
    {
        char character;
        input.get(character);
        // Process character.
    }
    return 0;
}
```