# Read first n letters from file to a string?

Tags: c++, file-io

I'm quite new with programming, and now I'm doing an exercise where I should use a cycle to read 25 first symbols from the file, which contains a string of 25 letters (+spaces if the name is shorter than 25) and two numbers. Example:

```
Whirlpool machine         324 789.99
```

as I imagine it should look something like this:

```
ifstream info("Information.txt");
string str;
int a;
double b;
for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{ // some kind of code to get first 25 symbols into a string.
}
info >> a >> b;
```

And I just can't seem to find the right code to get 25 characters straight to string. Any suggestions?

Comment: You may want to [read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) them?

Comment: Check out this answer to read the file character by character with no spaces: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12240035/2142219

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'm a begginer, I don't get half of the things shown in your example.

Comment: @Human that might work, but I'm looking for a solution with string type, not char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way is to use [`read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to read given number of characters:

```
int length = 25;             // num of chars you want to read
str.resize(length, ' ');     // reserve spaces
char* begin = &*str.begin();
info.read(begin, length);    // <- read it here
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`std::copy_n()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n) algorithm with stream buffer iterators:

```
std::string str;

std::copy_n(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(info.rdbuf()),
            25, std::back_inserter(str));
```

An approach that you might be more comfortable with is using `get()` with a `for()` loop:

```c++
for (char c; str.size() != 25 && info.get(c); )
    str += c;
```

Comment: The `copy_n` approach is not a bad idea, but you have one too many arguments when you call it.  (I'd also write the second loop snippet as `char ch; while ( str.size() != 25 && info.get( ch ) ) str += ch;`.

Comment: I always typedef `istream_iterator` and similar, but that's just me

Answer (score 0):

Given the context, I'd read the entire line into a string, using
`std::getline`, and then extract the substring.  Something like:

```
std::string line;
while ( std::getline( info, line ) ) {
    std::string header = line.substr( 0, 25 );
    //  and later...
    std::istringstream rest( line.substr( 25 ) );
    int a;
    double b;
    rest >> a >> b;
    //  ...
}
```

In general, when reading line oriented input, read the line, 
then use a `std::istringstream` to parse it.  Or, if there are
parts you can use "as is" (as is the case here), use them as is.