# Off-by-one errors when reading a file one chunk at a time

Tags: c++, file, c++17, file-read

`ifstream::readsome` is notoriously bad for reading chunks of a file due to implementation-defined issues. In my case, MSVC returns 0 on a freshly opened file.

I looked at their implementation and realized they're just calling `ifstream::read` under the hood:

**MSVC Implementation**

```cpp
streamsize __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL readsome(_Elem* _Str,
    streamsize _Count) { // read up to _Count characters into buffer, without blocking
    ios_base::iostate _State = ios_base::goodbit;
    _Chcount                 = 0;
    const sentry _Ok(*this, true);
    streamsize _Num;

    if (!_Ok) {
        _State |= ios_base::failbit; // no buffer, fail
    } else if ((_Num = _Myios::rdbuf()->in_avail()) < 0) {
        _State |= ios_base::eofbit; // no characters available
    } else if (0 < _Count && 0 < _Num) { // read available
        read(_Str, _Num < _Count ? _Num : _Count);
    }

    _Myios::setstate(_State);
    return gcount();
}
```

So I implemented my own that just calls `ifstream::read`:

**My Implementation**

```cpp
std::optional<std::string> ReadSomeStringFromFile(std::ifstream& ifs, std::streampos pos, std::streamsize count) noexcept {
    if(ifs && ifs.is_open()) {
        auto result = std::string(count, '\0');
        ifs.seekg(pos);
        ifs.read(result.data(), count);
        if(ifs.gcount()) {
            return result;
        }
    }
    return {};
}
```

**Usage:**

```cpp
std::streampos pos{0};
std::streamsize count{10};
std::ifstream ifs{g_options_filepath};
{
    auto stream = FileUtils::ReadSomeStringFromFile(ifs, pos, count);
    while(stream.has_value()) {
        DebuggerPrintf(stream.value().c_str());
        pos += count;
        stream = FileUtils::ReadSomeStringFromFile(ifs, pos, count);
    }
}
```

This works fine for binary files (I have a separate function for that), but for the string version *where I need to preserve the newline characters* produces an off-by-one error if the chunk contains a newline character. This causes the last character in the chunk to be duplicated as the first character in the next:

**Expected output**

```
difficulty=Normal
controlpref=Mouse
sound=5
music=5
cameraShakeStrength=1.000000
```

**Actual output**

```
difficulty=Normal
coontrolpref=Mouse
souund=5
musiic=5
camerraShakeStrength=1.000000
```

Using formatted `ifstream::get` by default uses the newline as a delimiter and skips it entirely (again, the newlines need to be preserved) and causes interleaved output and dropped characters:

```
difficult=Normalontrolpre=Mouseund=5ic=5raShakeStength=1.00000
```

**Question**

Is there a way around trying to use unformatted input functions on formatted data or should I just not try this with text data?

Comment: Make sure you open the file in `ios_base::binary` mode, otherwise you can't assume `seekg` uses an absolute file offset (and you would have to remember the `tellg` position after `read`, instead).

Comment: @dxiv Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of trying to read the file as text? As-is, reading as binary duplicates `<CR>` from the `<CR><LF>` newline pair and causes `<CR><CR><LF>` to be output. Outwardly, this looks like the newline is being duplicated. I guess I could manually consume the file one character at a time up to `pos`, but I fear that is going to be slow and cause problems when starting from the middle of the file.

Comment: `reading as binary duplicates <CR> from the <CR><LF>` Reading in binary mode reads literally what's on disk. If you get `<CR>` duplicated then that happens somewhere else after you've read the raw data. The other point remains that if you use it in text mode then you can only `seekg` to positions returned by `tellg`, *not* based on byte counts.

Comment: @dxiv I think my solution will work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Reading a file char-by-char will always work, but it's not entirely obvious how the new code answers the original question.

Comment: @dxiv Given the title and the question at the end, I think it boils down to: "I am getting off-by-one errors when trying to preserve whitespace. Am I using this wrong?" Answer: "Yes. You're doing it wrong. You should be doing it this way instead."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use `get` very often so I forgot it existed. Using [this answer as a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240113/421178) I came up with a solution:

(I double-checked, the other answer that uses `FormattedInput` as `(ifs >> std::noskipws >> ch)` gives the same results even though the `get` spec says it treats it as `UnformattedInput`)

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] std::optional<std::string> ReadSomeStringBufferFromFile(std::ifstream& ifs, std::streampos pos, std::streamsize count /*= 0u*/) noexcept {
    if(!(ifs && ifs.is_open())) {
        return {};
    }
    ifs.seekg(pos, std::ios::beg);

    //Would like to early-out here,
    //but MSVC ifstream::seekg doesn't set the fail bit,
    //so can't early-out until the get call.

    char ch{};
    std::string result{};
    result.reserve(count);
    bool readsome{false}; //If nothing read, make std::optional::has_value false.
    while(ifs && ifs.get(ch) && count > 0) {
        result.append(1, ch);
        --count;
        readsome |= true;
    }
    return readsome ? std::make_optional(result) : std::nullopt;
```